# How to prevent schtasks on Windows 7 from showing the command prompt after executing a task?

Tags: windows-7, batch, vbscript, schtasks

I am trying to get a scheduled task on Windows 7 to execute once a minute, using schtasks and a batch file.

My .bat batch file is:

```
@ECHO OFF
wscript "c:\http.vbs"
```

The .vbs script si a simple one, it performs a basic HTTP request:

```
Function HTTPGet()
    HttpRequest("my_url_is_here")
End Function
```

If I run the .bat file from a command prompt, it does its job nice and smooth. But if I try to  schedule the .bat, i.e.

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /tn "HTTPCheck" /tr "C:\HTTPCheck.bat"
```

I keep seeing the command prompt window for a split second on my screen, each minute.
Is there something I could do to prevent that window from flashing before my eyes?

Thanks!

L.E. I cannot use third party software, I want regular users to be able to run it w/o installing anything.

---

**Long story short, I need to make a HTTP GET request without having the command prompt window pop out on my screen every minute.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cristian,

I don't know how others choose to do it, but I've used JoeWare's "Quiet" program to spawn hidden (except from taskmgr) batch files in the background.

http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/quiet/index.htm

You could also wrap the batch file (a little funny since it is calling a vbs) inside a vbscript file such as:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\HTTPcheck.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The "0" parameter will force it to run hidden.

Comment: It works now, but I have to make do with 3 files:
HTTPcheck.vbs with your code,
HTTPcheck.bat which, in turn, calls
http.vbs

Wish I'd knew how to compact those files in one .vbs script, or at most 2 files, a .bat and a .vbs. Thanks!